# Javascript code for recording the clicks

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a set of websites.

In each website there is my Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div').click(function()
{
   // Do something
}
});
```

Then, I want to enable each user (via iFrame) to see the website and clicks on the banners. 
I have two problems:

1- How to get the clicks of each user to the database of my own site? Because javascript is within the pages of other website and I need to capture each click and send it to my own server for further processing and DB actions.

2- I ONLY want to capture the clicks of users who see the websites through my own iframe and not anywhere else.

thanks in advance

Comment: is your page and the web site loaded via iframe in the same domain

Comment: no they are totally different. and I only own iframe and the click website is my customer's site

Answer (score 0):

You can send analytics information when uesr click on the div: something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div').click(function()
{
   if (getURLParameter("myIfram"){
      var url= "http://your-end-point";
      $.ajax('POST',URL,data :{click:"$(this).val()}");
   }
}
});
```

you also need to recognize if they are clicking from your iframe, i suggest you to set a special url for your iframe and then ask for this parameter

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
return decodeURI(
    (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
);
```

}

Comment: Can please explain more about URL configuration. I didn't understand